# Cannot Install Ubuntu 20.04 on my Asus X507UB (Facing multiple issues)

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, system-installation, pcie

I'm a newbie to Linux,
Ubuntu or any other distro of ubuntu wont install properly (5.4 kernel).

1. `PCIe Bus error severity=corrected, Type=Physical layer` /Sometimes cannot even live boot.
   IMG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlNES.jpg
2. Installer freezes on "Who are you" or even sometimes on random screen. IMG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdvFA.jpg
3. some more PCIe error during installation. IMG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJNR1.jpg

Things I've tried...

1. Multiple ubuntu distros like kubuntu, mx Linux, pop os etc, although distros like deepin & ubuntu
   budgie works fine.
2. Tried MBR and GPT format.
3. Tried `Normal Install`, `Minimal`, `with/out proprietary drivers`.
4. Tried clean installation without windows and with windows. When I went back to window I saw these
   drivers link and when I installed these drivers it was fixed so
   maybe there is something wrong with ubuntu drivers.
5. Updated BIOS from 306 to 307.

```
System Manufacturer:            ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
System Model:                   X507UB
System Type:                    x64-based PC
System SKU Processor:           Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz, 1992 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical 
                                Processor(s)
GPU:                            Intel(R) HD 520
GPU:                            Nvidia GeForce MX110
HDD:                            1 TB(GPT partition format)
BIOS Version/Date:              American Megatrends Inc. X507UB.307, 7/24/2019
SMBIOS Version:                 3.0
Embedded Controller Version:    255.255
BIOS Mode:                      UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer:         ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
BaseBoard Product:              X507UB
BaseBoard Version:              1.0
Secure Boot State:              ON
Virtualization-based security   Not enabled
Device Encryption Support:      Elevation Required to View
Hyper-V - Virtualization        Yes
Enabled in Firmware:
Hyper-V - Data Execution        Yes
Protection:
```

Comment: If you need any logs or other info, HMU.

Comment: Don't know if it will help, but Secure Boot should be OFF.

Comment: @Eagle_Mike I don't see any option such as Secure Boot in my BIOS settings but I did try turning off Fast Boot in my BIOS, still the same. :-(